# Automatic selector updated according to the parent selector selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have designed everything on my mvc, but I don't know the syntax to retrieve data from respone json.

this is the parent selector whose location code will be retrieved later :

```html
<div class="form-group row">
 <label for="kode_lokasi" class="control-label col-lg-2"> Kode Lokasi</label>
 <div class="col-lg-3">
  <?php echo form_dropdown("input[kode_lokasi]", $arr_combo_kode_lokasi, set_value("input[kode_lokasi]"), 'id="kode_lokasi" class="form-control chosen" onChange="lokasi_ajax()"  data-placeholder="Pilih"  required');?>
  <?php echo form_error('input[kode_lokasi]','<span class="label label-danger">','</span>'); ?>
 </div>
</div>
```

and this is the selector which will contain the item data after the existence of the location code obtained :

```html
<select class="form-control chosen" id="repkodebarang">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
  </select>
```

Js :

```js
function lokasi_ajax() {
  var kode_lokasi = $('#kode_lokasi').val();

  $.ajax({
   url : '<?= base_url() ?>index.php/asset/asset_dijual_proses/lokasi_ajax',
   data: 'kode_lokasi='+kode_lokasi,
   success : function (data) {
    var json = data;
    value = JSON.parse(json);

    $.each(value, function (i, data) {
     $("#repkodebarang").appends('<option>'+value.item_barang+'</option>');    
    })
    
   }
  });
 }
```

Php Controller :

```html
function lokasi_ajax()
 {
  $kode_lokasi = $_GET['kode_lokasi'];
  $data =array();

  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id_reg, item_lokasi, item_barang FROM asset_item 
   WHERE item_lokasi= '$kode_lokasi'");
  foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
   $data[] = array(
    // 'kode_aset' => $row->id_reg,
    // 'item_lokasi' => $row->item_lokasi,
    'item_barang' => $row->item_barang 
   );
  }
  echo json_encode($data);
 }
```

json's responese data works like this :
[Json Data Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV44I.png)

but the data still can't be added to my selector :
[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNxeV.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote a possible solution for your problem, comments are mentioned wherever necessary, see if it helps you.

```
success : function (data) {
    var json = data;
    value = JSON.parse(json);
    let $html = ''; // initialize a variable to store html
    $.each(value, function () {
        $html += '<option>' + value.item_barang + '</option>';  // append new data on each iteration        
    })
    $('#repkodebarang').append($html); // append the element to the select element
}
```